# Pycharm py.test coverage 'Coverage' object has no attribute 'export'

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, coverage.py

I'm trying to run a py.test with coverage in pycharm. On my home pc it works like a charm, however on my laptop I'm getting this stacktrace

```
/home/david/PycharmProjects/pyCardDeck/virtualenv/bin/python /opt/pycharm/helpers/coverage_runner/run_coverage.py run --omit=\"/opt/pycharm/helpers*\" /opt/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py -p pytest_teamcity /home/david/PycharmProjects/pyCardDeck tests
Testing started at 13:15 ...
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/david/PycharmProjects/pyCardDeck, inifile: 
plugins: cov-2.3.1
collected 35 items

tests/test_card.py ..
tests/test_deck.py ..............................Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm/helpers/coverage_runner/run_coverage.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/david/PycharmProjects/pyCardDeck/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 753, in main
...

========================== 35 passed in 0.89 seconds ===========================
    status = CoverageScript().command_line(argv)
  File "/home/david/PycharmProjects/pyCardDeck/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 480, in command_line
    return self.do_run(options, args)
  File "/home/david/PycharmProjects/pyCardDeck/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 638, in do_run
    self.coverage.export()
AttributeError: 'Coverage' object has no attribute 'export'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Running py.test --cov manually works, so it's something inside of Pycharm magic. My laptop is running with Pycharm 2016.1.4 and coverage 4.2

Comment: That line in cmdline.py should read `self.coverage.save()`.  It's never said `export`.  You should reinstall coverage.py

Comment: Reinstall worked, thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line in cmdline.py should read `self.coverage.save()`. It's never said `export`. You should reinstall coverage.py.  I have no idea what changed it.